# Crash Canvas SwiftUI in .onAppear

Tags: swiftui

The preview of the canvas in swiftUI is broken when I put this function.
I don't understand what the problem is, if I comment it, it works perfectly, but if I don't comment it, it crashes.
I am a bit desperate because when the canvas breaks I find it very difficult to program.
My code is:

```
struct DashboardView: View {
    @State var user : String = "aa.aas"
    @State var iniciales : String = "AA"
    @State var fichado : Bool = false
    private func cargaDatos(){
        let defaults    = UserDefaults.standard
        self.user = defaults.string(forKey: "user") ?? "Unknown user"
        let misIniciales = self.user.components(separatedBy: ".")
        self.iniciales = String(misIniciales[0].prefix(1) + misIniciales[1].prefix(1))


    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {

           ...

        }.onAppear{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cargaDatos()
            }

        }
    }
}

struct DashboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DashboardView()
    }
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

this has nothing to do with the canvas...it crashes everywhere.
The debugger is your friend and it says:

2020-03-30 18:51:19.909408+0200 crashcanvas[22116:930944] Fatal error: Index out of range: file /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
(lldb) po misIniciales
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : "Unknown user"

-> reason: if nothing is in the user, the array misIniciales will have one item, but you assume here

```
 self.iniciales = String(misIniciales[0].prefix(1) + misIniciales[1].prefix(1))
```

that there are always two items by accessing misIniciales[1]